# Squares in the sequence $ a3^n+b$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, square-numbers

> Let $a \in \mathbb{N}, b \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Define $n$ to be the largest nonnegative integer such that the sequence $ \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n \}$ consists entirely of squares of natural numbers, where $a_n := a3^n+b$?  For which values of $a,b$ does $n$ achieve a maximum value?

I managed to prove that the sequence is finite for any given $a,b$, but I have not gone further than this.  I would be happy with any hint. Thank you

Comment: Interesting question.  Can you share your proof that the sequence is finite?  I'm curious in particular whether your length bound can be made uniform in $a,b$ or whether it might be arbitrarily large depending on $a,b$.

Comment: Let $$ 3^na+b = x^2, 3^{n+2}a+b = y^2 $$ then $$ 4x^2-y^2 = (2x+y)(2x-y) = 3b \Rightarrow 2x+y \leq 3b $$ But for large $n$, the sum is $2x + y$ and unbounded

Comment: How it seems to me that the answer is about $ n = 10$

Comment: Ah very nice.  For a stronger bound, I’m thinking this is fairly similar to the classical “no 4 squares in arithmetic progression” problem.  I would guess that $(w^2-z^2) = 3(z^2-y^2)=9(y^2-x^2)$ gives rise to an elliptic curve that can be studied.  Though if you have found any examples with $n>4$ then that would suggest something more is going on.

Comment: Somehow i am missing a verb in the question. (Also no question mark decorator...) So we are starting with $a,b$, some constants, then we build (overloading $a$) the sequence $(a_n)$ (which depends on $a,b$), so $a_1=3a+b$, $a_2=9a+b$, $a_3=27a+b$, and so on, then consider $N$ maximal such that $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_N$ are perfect squares, it also depends on $a,b$, so let us denote it by $N(a,b)$, and the question wants  $$\max_{\substack{a\in\Bbb N\\b\in\Bbb Z}}N(a,b)\ ?$$

Comment: @dan_fulea I'm only learning English for six months, please correct me

Comment: @VladislavKharlamov I made some minor changes to the wording, please confirm that I didn't betray your intent.

Comment: @ErickWong Yes, everything is great. Many thanks!

Comment: For $1\le a,b \le 10^4$, the maximum is $3$ (for example occuring for $a=4$ and $b=13$). I am currently checking the range $[1,10^5]$ , no better example yet.

Comment: $3$ is the maximum for $1\le a,b \le 10^5$

Comment: b just integer.

Comment: $a=41860$ and $b=117469$ gives a chain of length $4$

Comment: If $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are square & $a$ & $b$ are coprime: $a=0$  mod 4. For each prime factor $p$ of $b$, 3 is a quadratic residue mod $p$, i.e. $p$ has the form $12k\pm 1$ (such numbers are in OEIS A072330). $b=1$ mod 4, so the number of $b$'s prime factors of the form $12k-1$ is even. @Peter's $a=41860=2^2 (12+1)(2*12-1)(3*12-1)$; not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: Allowing $b$ to be negative yield a nice small solution with four squares too: $a=60$, $b=(-99)$.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.- I give here **a necessary condition** that could help anyone who wants to try to get an answer. I am engaged in another task that requires me all my attention so I do not have enough time for try to solve this challenging problem.

One can use both periodicity of powers of $3$  modulo $10$ and squares modulo ${10}$.

Put $A3^n+B=\square$ with $A\equiv a\pmod{10}$ and $B\equiv b\pmod{10}$. It follows

$a3^n+b\equiv c= 0,1,4,9,6,5\pmod{10}$
$$\begin{cases}a+b=10x+c\\3a+b=10y+c=10x+c+2a\\7a+b=10z+c=10x+c+5a\\9a+b=10w+c=10x+c+8a\end{cases}$$ By simple subtraction of second and third (or third and fourth) equations we get $a=0$.

Consequently one has to study the equations
$$10x3^n+10y+c=z^2;\qquad c=0,1,4,9,6,5$$ or,equivalently, $$10x3^n+10y=(z-\sqrt c)(z+\sqrt c)$$
With the convenient fact that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt5)$ and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt6)$ are norm-Euclidean quadratic fields.